# boost::enable_if и static_cast

Tags: c++, boost

Не могу понять как написать такую хотелку.

Есть шаблонный метод `template<class T> T get(boost::any)`, который достает из boost::any значение, хранящееся в одном из заранее известных типов: int, double, string и должен скастить его к типу Т
Кусочек кода:

```
template<class T> T get(const boost::any& item)
{
    if (const int * value = boost::any_cast<int>(&item)) {
        return runtime_cast<T>(*value);
    } else if (const double * value = boost::any<double>(&item)) {
        return runtime_cast<T>(*value);
    } else if (const std::string * value = boost::any<std::string>(&item)) {
        return runtime_cast<T>(*value);
    }
    return T();
}
```

Есть типовая реализация runtime_cast

```
template<class ResultType, class BaseType>
ResultType runtime_cast(const BaseType& baseValue) 
{
    return static_cast<ResultType>(baseValue);
}
```

Есть объкты, классы которых мы не можем изменять, но можем написать для них свою функцию runtime_cast, например:

```
class C;
template<>
C runtime_cast<C, std::string>(const std::string& xml_text) 
{
    Xml xml(xml_text);
    return С(xml.attribue("a1"), xml.attribute("a2");
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать `C c = get<C>(anyValue)` будут ошибка в runtime_cast, что не могу сделать `static_cast<С>(int)` что логично.

Есть мысль написать такое через boost::enable_if

```
// дефолтная реализация
template<class ResultType, class BaseType>
ResultType runtime_cast(const BaseType& baseValue) 
{
    throw std::runtime_error("bad cast");
}

// типовая реализация для типов приводящихся static_cast`ом
template<class ResultType, class BaseType, boost::enable_if<can_static_cast<ResultType, BaseType>> // <- Вот тут не знаю как сделать :(
ResultType runtime_cast(const BaseType& baseValue) 
{
    return static_cast<ResultType>(baseValue);
}

// Ну где угодно для кастомных объектов
class C;
template<>
C runtime_cast<C, std::string>(const std::string& xml_text) 
{
    Xml xml(xml_text);
    return С(xml.attribue("a1"), xml.attribute("a2");
}
```

Может кто решал подобную задачу? Возможно есть другой способ ее решения.

Ограничения: есть boost, нет C++11. Но если есть решения только с C++11-17, я готов его расмотреть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути, вместо `can_static_cast` можете попробовать использовать [`boost::is_convertible`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_convertible.html).